# How to know when 2 persons cross in the street ? (Geofences...)

Tags: android, geolocation, android-geofence

I want to create an Android app with a simple concept : if 2 persons who have downloaded my app are crossing in the street, I want to send them a notification (immediately).

I started to use the geofences concept, but I don't know if it is the most appropriate. So my questions are the following :

- Using the geofences (every user have his own geofence, so you are notified when entering an other user geofence), how can I make the geofence following the user when he is moving ? (with enough precision but without too much power consumption)
- Is there another concept that is more appropriate to my problem than the geofences ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both persons are in movement, I think you need to call the position frequently and therefore it doesn't make sense anymore to use Geofences. Instead you would calculate the difference between them and push a notification from server when a certain threshold is reached.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But won't it be very complex to calculate very often all the differences of position between all the users of my app ? I mean, let's say 100 persons are using my app, I'll have to calculate 99+98+97+...+1 differences of position every 5 seconds if I want to be sure to know if someone crosses another one. Is there a trick I didn't know about to avoid it ?

Comment: but I think that is a different question... so you are actually searching for a elegant algorithm to compare distances of users?... Anyways you probably want do this on server side, right?

Comment: @PeppermintPaddy It absolutely needs to be done server side, or you'd need to push the location of all users to all other users-  which in addition to not scaling is a massive breach of privacy

Comment: If a use server-side, yes i will need an elegant algorithm to compare distances of users. But isn't there a way to do it client-side ? Because I don't really have a server at my disposal. I was hoping to find a technology that could allow that, without creating a breach of privacy.

Comment: @Damien No.  First off, how would all your users even know where the other users are, without a server telling them?  SO no matter what, you will need a server.  Secondly, if you want to check it on the client, you need to send everyone's location to the client.  That's a privacy issue.

Comment: I think you need a server anyways to keep track of your users... on the server side you could split the big problem into smaller pieces by rasterizing the world and just calculating distances for all users in one square... to overcome the issue when a user is at the edge you could build a second raster that is shifted half delta lat and lon... this could be probably also calculated decentralized anonymously via encryption on the client side... I also think if a user agrees to be tracked by other users it's not a privacy issue, but I hope nobody would go this far

Comment: OK, thanks a lot to both of you. I will do as you recommend. I do need a server. I'll try to implement a good algorithm and to avoid any breach of privacy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want use geofences with server side will be more easy for app(in android u only can register 100 geofences) you can check in server the nearest users from you.

but if you need check user very close to you i think is better use Bluetooth, you can emulate ibeacons and the app can register beacon region and monitoring it. dont care gps signal and battery drain. In android you can use altbeacon open source lib for ibeacons/eddystone.

contact me if need more help and sorry my english ;)